# How to get X Y coordinates (without moving mouse)

Tags: delphi, charts, teechart

with MouseMove procedure, I can get X and Y pos. by this code:

```
///////////

var

  XVal: double;
  YVal: double;

begin

  XVal:=Chart1.Axes.Bottom.CalcPosPoint(X);
  YVal:=Chart1.Axes.Left.CalcPosPoint(Y);

  Chart1.Title.Text[0]:=FormatFloat('#.##', XVal) + ' - ' + FormatFloat('#.##', YVal);
end;

////////////
```

It's OK. But I would like get the X and Y coordinates of a series1.Value (single value, it is 'somewhere' on the chart) by clicking a (separate) button and not by moving the mouse above this value. Maybe it is a very simple question. Thanks.

Comment: If you're clicking on a button, how is the program supposed to know what object you want the position of?

Comment: Use `Mouse.CursorPos` to read the coordinates of the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions of series:

`CalcXPos` - to get screen X-coordinate by index of value (in serie)
`CalcXPosValue` - to get screen X-coordinate by value

(`CalcYPos`/`CalcYPosValue` for Y-coordinate)